# Symfony Component ErrorHandler Error ClassNotFoundError #93

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to run this boilerplate: https://github.com/thecodingmachine/symfony-boilerplate

I am currently on my MACOS.

I am using Docker Desktop for MACOS.

When I run `docker-compose up webapp api`, I see the following error:

[image]

Could anyone shine some light on what's going on?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried stopping all running containers and restarting them? I've tried just cloning that repo and running the same command - it exited with an error about migrations but that seems to be expected

Comment: Yeah... I did try that...

Comment: I've got it installed on a separate machine. However when I navigate to the url provided by the webapp (172.0.18.2:3000), the page just keeps loading. Could you run `docker-compose up` and see whether the link provided by the webapp service works for you?

Comment: Even if I try `localhost:3000` or `symfony-boilerplate.localhost:3000`, there's nothing that shows up, no errors in the logs either.

Comment: I don't think the api is exposed to the host, if you look at the https://github.com/thecodingmachine/symfony-boilerplate/blob/master/docker-compose.yml and search for "ports:" you can see only the traefik container has mapped ports.

Comment: So how exactly should I configure this to get it to work? I added `ports` "3000:3000" to the webapp in docker-compose.yml and removed `expose` but it still isn't working.

Comment: NVM I got it to work....

Comment: If you think it's useful to other people you might want to add an answer below

Comment: I believe the error was due to using docker on a mac with the apple chip. I changed laptops and used one with a intel chip and docker worked.